# Is there anyway I can access "Environments" variables in .yml file for Insomnia?

Tags: insomnia

For example, I have "Base Environment" like this.

```
When I have "Base Environment" like this,
{
  "base_url": "https://sample.co.jp"
}
```

Is there anyway I can reference "base_url" in .yml file?
It would be useful to use "Environment" in .yml to write API document.

So far I searched the documents in Insomnia to find how to reference "Base Environment", but I couldn't find it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from official support team.
At the moment, there is not way to do this.